# Playwright won't run in VSCode Dev Container on mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, playwright, vscode-devcontainer, playwright-test

The simple playwright test in [this repo](https://github.com/dfberry/github-who-playwright) runs on mac with vscode using the npm script `test`. If I open the same repo in a devcontainer (in ./devcontainer), the test fails, with an error about missing dependencies:

```
browserType.launch: 
    ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
    ║ Host system is missing a few dependencies to run browsers. ║
    ║ Please install them with the following command:            ║
    ║                                                            ║
    ║     sudo npx playwright install-deps                       ║
    ║                                                            ║
    ║ <3 Playwright Team                                         ║
    ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I've tried the container as 14, 16, 14-bullseye, and 16-bullseye. While I am on a mac at the moment, the CICD will be true linux.

1. how do I get the container to run the test on my mac
2. how do I get the same container to work regardless of a mac or linux

Comment: I'm wondering, how useful it might be to have a web-based version of Playwright to avoid issues configuring local environment? Trying to build one: https://endtest.dev

Comment: I would rather have it in a container so it can be used in any environment, such as a GitHub action. I trust containers more than the web for repeatability.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I get the container to run the test on my mac

As the error message says the system inside container is missing some of the browser dependencies. You can either create the container based on the official [docker image](https://playwright.dev/docs/docker) or run `sudo npx playwright install-deps` command after `npm install` in `"postCreateCommand"`.

> how do I get the same container to work regardless of a mac or linux

Docker container should automatically work on both mac and linux host systems, you don't need to do anything extra.